# Message: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I get this message.
I have 4 applications of which 3 work fine and the fourth not.

`hosts` file looks like this **(* used to sensor application names)**

```
127.0.0.1       Out*****Series
::1             Out*****Series

127.0.0.1       M****Us
::1             M****Us

127.0.0.1       Paed
::1             Paed

127.0.0.1       Me****AQ
::1             Me****AQ
```

`httpd-vhosts.conf` setup like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\WEB\Out*****"
    ServerName Out*****Series
    <Directory  "E:\WEB\Out*****">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\WEB\M****Us"
    ServerName M****Us
    <Directory  "E:\WEB\M****Us">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

>>>>>>>>>>>>>THIS IS THE ONE GIVING ME THE FORBIDDEN MESSAGE -> OTHERS WORK
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\WEB\Paed"
    ServerName Paed
    <Directory   "E:\WEB\Paed">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:\WEB\Me****AQ"
    ServerName Me****AQ
    <Directory  "E:\WEB\Me****AQ">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing.

I did the `net stop dnscache` and `net start dnscache`.
I did restart all services in Wamp.
I restarted the machine. Still other 3 apps work, this one not.

Please help the blind to see again.

Comment: what about index file setting?

Comment: Please elaborate. what setting are you talking about?   I did however do it exactly like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23990618/2240163

Comment: When you are accessing "/" (root or any other directory of the site), there are two ways Apache can respond: 1) If there is a configured index file (index.html, index.php...) then it will be shown. 2) If there is no index file, or if it is not configured, just a list of files in the directory will be shown. But if directory listing is forbidden (which is another config option), you will get the error that you have posted.

Comment: Assuming your virtual hosts share one main config file, I'd say your "problem" site does not have an index file.

Comment: Okay maybe I should delete the question. here is why. All the other apps default to `index.php` as you said @AndreiNikolaenko, but for this one it does not, but when I type `index.php` after the given path it works. Why its not defaulting `index.php` I dont know, but there is definitely one.

Comment: Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` directive into the `<Directory>` section of the problematic virtual host.

Comment: Nope no change in reaction.

Comment: Well then also check if there is any suspicious .htaccess file in the directory, and as a last resort, rename the virtual host, maybe the name contains some error.